# Python can't use ** outside of function definition

Tags: python, keyword-argument

Disclaimer: I am new to Python.

If you read [this article](https://treyhunner.com/2018/10/asterisks-in-python-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them/), it lists `**` as being able to unpack dictionaries.  I was trying this out.

1. `my_dict = {"key1": 1, "key2": {"inner_key": 3} }`
2. `unpacked_dict = **my_dict`

Returns: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

What am I missing?  I know `**` is used mainly with `**kwargs`, is my problem that `**` can only be used in a function definition?

Comment: What were you expecting `unpacked_dict` to be?

Comment: The purpose of `**` is to translate the dict into function kwargs, which only makes sense in the context of a function call.

Comment: That's not correct in Python 3.5+: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it to unpack it into other dictionaries. It doesn't work in the way I assume you are trying to do it which is taken inner dictionaries from values and make them all part of the same level.  From the article you referenced:

> For example we can copy a dictionary while adding a new value to it:
>
> ```
> >>> date_info = {'year': '2020', 'month': '01', 'day': '7'}
> >>> event_info = {**date_info, 'group': "Python Meetup"}
> >>> event_info
> {'year': '2020', 'month': '01', 'day': '7', 'group': 'Python Meetup'}
> ```
>
> Or copy/merge dictionaries while overriding particular values:
>
> ```
> >>> event_info = {'year': '2020', 'month': '01', 'day': '7', 'group': 'Python Meetup'}
> >>> new_info = {**event_info, 'day': "14"}
> >>> new_info
> {'year': '2020', 'month': '01', 'day': '14', 'group': 'Python Meetup'}
> ```

This was added as of Python 3.5+, more info is in [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/).

Comment: Thank you @GiraffeMan91 for the complete answer explaining rationale and providing an example.  This makes sense now.  Cheers!